# python remove element containing namespace

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to remove an element in an xml which contains a namespace.
Here is my code:

```
templateXml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Metadata xmlns="http://www.amazon.com/UnboxMetadata/v1">
<Movie>
        <CountryOfOrigin>US</CountryOfOrigin>
        <TitleInfo>
                <Title locale="en-GB">The Title</Title>
                <Actor>
                        <ActorName locale="en-GB">XXX</ActorName>
                        <Character locale="en-GB">XXX</Character>
                </Actor>
        </TitleInfo>    
</Movie>
</Metadata>"""

from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring(templateXml)

namespaces = {'ns':'http://www.amazon.com/UnboxMetadata/v1'}

for checkActor in tree.xpath('//ns:Actor', namespaces=namespaces):
    etree.strip_elements(tree, 'ns:Actor')
```

In my actual XML I have lots of  tags, So I am trying to search for the Actor tags which contain XXX and completely remove that whole  tag and its contents. But it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`remove()`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove) method:

```
for checkActor in tree.xpath('//ns:Actor', namespaces=namespaces):
    checkActor.getparent().remove(checkActor)

print etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)
```

prints:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<Metadata xmlns="http://www.amazon.com/UnboxMetadata/v1">
<Movie>
        <CountryOfOrigin>US</CountryOfOrigin>
        <TitleInfo>
                <Title locale="en-GB">The Title</Title>
                </TitleInfo>    
</Movie>
</Metadata>
```